# How to depend on opencv-python OR opencv-python-headless?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, python-packaging

In the setup.py file for my package I currently have the line

```
install_requires=['opencv-python'],
```

because my package uses some OpenCV functions. When installing my package, `opencv-python` is automatically installed as well.

But I want to deploy my package sometimes on a development host where `opencv-python` is installed, and sometimes on a server where `opencv-python-headless` is installed. Both packages are fine for me. Currently, when I install my package on the server, it will always cause `opencv-python` to be installed in addition to the existing `opencv-python-headless` package. According to https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#installation-and-usage installing both packages in parallel is not a good thing.

Also, in some environments `opencv-contrib-python-headless` is installed; so there is a third option that would satisfy the dependency for me.

Is there a way to specify these "alternative" dependencies for `opencv-python` in my setup.py file, so that *either* `opencv-python` *or* `opencv-python-headless` is installed? Would it help to move to some other packaging tool to get this feature?

Comment: if pip/requirements can't model this for opencv-python's current flavor naming, you'd probably want to figure out what mechanisms these things *do* offer for package flavors/optionals, and then file an issue with https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python and request that schema. it's been trouble to many people, not just you.